# Acumatica - NonStockItem Screen on AlloAddNew in Page

Tags: acumatica

Good Day!

I have a PXSelector field in DAC that only show non-stock items

```
    public abstract class inventoryID : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBInt]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
                                LeftJoin<RECOInventoryItem, On<RECOInventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>,
                                Where<RECOInventoryItem.inventoryID, IsNull,
                                    And<InventoryItem.itemType, Equal<ItemType.NON_STOCK>,
                                        And<InventoryItem.stkItem, Equal<False>>>>>),
                          typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
                          typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
                          DescriptionField = typeof(InventoryItem.descr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory")]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
```

I also have a selector in my page that allows edit and allows add new methods

```
        <px:PXSelector ID="edInventoryID" runat="server" DataField="InventoryID" AllowEdit="true" AllowAddNew="true">
        </px:PXSelector>
```

Now, my problem lies with the edit(pencil) button in the User Interface. When I'm clicking the edit button, with the item that i want to edit, I am being redirected to Non-Stock Items page,

But when I want to add another Non-stock Item by using the edit(pencil) button, I am redirected to the Stock Items page.

I already set my PrimaryGraph.

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(PropertyMaint))]
public class RECOInventoryItem : Audit, IBqlTable
```

How do you set the AllowAddNew redirect to Non-Stock Item Page instead of the Stock Item Page.

How do you override the PxPrimaryGraph of the InventoryItem so that the graph that i'm redirecting to is Non-stock Item, instead of Stock Item.

Thank you so much for the advice and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PXPrimaryGraph` can handle binding 1 DAC to multiple graphs using BQL conditions on the DAC fields as shown on InventoryItem DAC:

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(new Type[] 
                {
                   typeof(NonStockItemMaint),
                   typeof(InventoryItemMaint)
                },
                new Type[] 
                {
                   typeof(Where<InventoryItem.stkItem, Equal<False>>),
                   typeof(Where<InventoryItem.stkItem, Equal<True>>)
                })]
```

This works well with `AllowEdit` functionality because the `InventoryItem.stkItem` field used for the graph redirection is already populated in the record you want to edit.

When you create a new record with `AllowAddNew` though I suspect the field `InventoryItem.stkItem` will be null or always defaulted to the same value by `PXDefault` attribute. This would have the side effect of always redirecting to the same graph.

As you can probably guess `AllowAddNew` doesn't have any options or programmatic interface to influence it's behavior so it is pretty limited in what it can do. For that reason I don't think you can override it's behavior.

This leave creating your own action button as the only option I know to achieve your use case. You can style the button to show a `+` icon and no text like AllowAddNew does. You would still be limited on where you can place that button because `Selector` popup windows also lack options and programmatic interface.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot, I now have a general idea on what i need to do to have my Non-stock item.